# jQuery selector targeting element with id AND class does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, callback

I have the following event-handling function:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#button .submitb', function(e){alert();});
```

jQuery IS included in the html document. But, if I click on a `<div id="button" class="submitb">Go!</div>` nothing happens. I don't even get an error in the chrome-console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to target the same element, then you cannot have a `space` between selectors, that would mean `.submitb` **descendent of** `#button`.

And since **the element has ID** you just actually need the id selector:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#button', function(e){alert();});
```

**EDIT:**

**You cannot have multiple buttons with same ID**!! then you should use just the `class`. Or give them different ID-ending like `_0`, `_1` and target with `[id^=button]`

Comment: with `space` is a _descendant_, not a _child_ selector.

Comment: Thanks! The Problem is, that I have multiple #button's, since I use it for CSS-Styling. But its working without the space, thanks :)!

Comment: @user2595546, check my updated answer. You cannot have multiple ID's, it will give you problems

Comment: @Sergio Oh, didn't knew that! Hmm.... So, should I make "button" a class (for styling) and "submitb" an ID? Then there would not be multiple IDs?

Comment: @user2595546, use a `class` to elements that you want to use/target together and `id` to some, specific, (unique named) that you want to target alone. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

`.submitb` is not a descendant of `#button` to target it with jquery just use the id `#button'

like this

`jQuery(document).on('click', '#button', function(e){alert();});`

If you want to target a div id with that class aswell you can you just move the space.

like this

`jQuery(document).on('click', '#button.submitb', function(e){alert();});`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But, why? How should an selecter look like if I want to match the elements id AND class?

Comment: `#button .submitb`  is `ancestor descendant`, `#button > .submitb`  would be `parent > child`

Comment: @user2595546 Just remove the space. `'#button.submitb'`