# Bootstrap Carousel's active item issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn about carousel of bootstrap base on [this one](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VolV).
But when i tried to make  simulated one. But it won't work as its demo. 
The active item can't change when user click on another `<li>`. I tried but still not figure out why. 
This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">About<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">Projects<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">Portfolio<small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</small></a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/cccccc/ffffff" />
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/999999/cccccc">
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x400/dddddd/333333">
      </div>
      <!-- End Item -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Carousel Inner -->

  </div>
</div>
```

my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
  });
  $('#myCarousel.nav a').on('click', function() {
    clickEvent = true;
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong? I'm still newbie with this jquery.
On his demo, why did he use like this:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {...});
```

I thought we can only use :

```
$('#myCarousel').on('click',function(){...});
```

This is what i was learnt from [Jquery click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

This is my [source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzZZN5V9Ma4pRmFTNXoxVTNtNTg)

Comment: I forget to add my custom `js `. Sorry everyone and thank for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I tried same js and created this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muhsin84/DTcHh/28289/)** it is working fine for me

Please check this and let me know.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
   interval:   4000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to target the element which has `#myCarousel` with class .nav, but your class is under that id. So in order to target anchor tag your have to tell `#myCarousel` go and find the child with class `.nav` by putting space between selectors.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28286/)

Change this

```
  $('#myCarousel.nav a')
```

to

```
 $('#myCarousel .nav a')
```

for your question on selection, check this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346554/jquery-document-onclick-selector-callback-does-not-call-on-click)

Comment: i changed as i suggested. But still can't change active item of carousel

Comment: Check out fiddle.

Comment: i copied your code too. But I won't work. I don't know why. it still can't change active item, active slider still runs well.

Comment: May be difference in jquery version, check that out

Comment: using `jquery-3.1.1.min.js` and bootstrap 3.3.7. Which version did u use???

Comment: No issue with above version, see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28288/  I have used the same version. check your console may be some error you may have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132054/discussion-between-afsar-and-hanata).